# How to sort a data.frame by all columns

Tags: r, sorting

I am trying to sort a database by each column in the database.
I have tried with the following code

```
db <- db[order(db[,1],db[,2],db[,3],db[,4],db[,5],db[,6]), ]
```

and it works perfectly. However I would like to write it in a more efficient way, because I don't know if the database will always have 6 columns.
Is there a way to do this more efficiently?

Answer (score 5):

Here are three approaches to do that:

1) base R

```
data(mtcars)
mtcars <- mtcars[do.call(order, mtcars),]
```

2) dplyr

```
data(mtcars)
library(dplyr)
mtcars <- arrange_all(mtcars)
```

3) data.table

```
data(mtcars)    
library(data.table)
setDT(mtcars)
setorderv(mtcars, names(mtcars))
```